# Using SpecFlow Featurs as subroutines in other features

Tags: specflow

I may have this completely wrong, but I've been searching available documentation and googling for 2 weeks now, and have my head completely wrapped around the axle.

I am trying to use SpecFlow to write a regression test for our site.  This means that I want to exercise all the features so that if we inadvertently broke something, it will catch it.

The site is basically an incident reporting portal.  The home page has about 50 different buttons, each of which opens up the data entry pages for a different class of incident.

The data entry pages are arranged in a "wizard" fashion, where it starts with a page of general questions, then moves on to a page of more specific questions and so on. The questions are more or less grouped in the classic "who/what/when/where/why" grouping, with one wizard page for each group, so that we don't overwhelm the user with 100 questions presented all at once.

Exactly which pages are needed depends on the particular type of incident.  Some incident types have as many as 8 pages, some as few as 3.

Our specifications for each page are framed in BDD style - Given/When/Then. So it is very natural to translate those specifications into SpecFlow features, and I have done that, at least for the first page of general information questions. But the Scenario had about 30+ steps in it.

I have also written another Feature for testing from the home page -

```
    Given I'm logged in on the home page
    When I clicked the button for XYZ ticket
    Then it opens XYZ ticket 
    And the General Information page is displayed.
```

And I can drive that scenario from a table so that I can test as many different incident types as I want.
So far so good.
But now I want to add

```
    And the General Information page requirements are verified
```

Where the step definition for that last clause would run the whole scenario for the general information page.  In other words, I want to use that other scenario that I have written as a subroutine in this one.
(And then I want to go on and do the same for each of the other wizard pages. But let's get the first one first!)

I can't figure out a way to do that.  I tried writing the step definition for the above clause to invoke the step definitions of the General Information scenario, e.g.

```
    Given("I am on the General Information page")
    When ("I click this checkbox")
    Then ("This happens")
```

You used to be able to do that (although that would still be a lot of repetition).  But now that's giving a warning message that function is deprecated and will be removed (and since I've now upgraded, it may already have been removed - I haven't tried it since I upgraded.)  The github issues page (https://github.com/SpecFlowOSS/SpecFlow/issues/1733  has a lot of discussion on it, none of which sheds any light on how to do what I'm trying to do. The primary author (SabotageAndi) seemed to be saying "That's a bad thing; don't do that" without really giving any alternative, at least none that I was able to understand.

Can anyone give me a direction for how to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

> I want to use that other scenario that I have written as a subroutine
> in this one.

You can't reuse scenarios defined in feature files.

The best you can do is create a new Step that reuse already defined steps by calling them direcly (jameswtelfer comment on 31 Jan in github issue you provide).